# How can I use process.env.Namespace in interface as the key in react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, environment-variables

this is the user interface when I fetch user from auth0.

```
export interface IUser {
  family_name: string;
  given_name: string;
  locale: string;
  name: string;
  nickname: string;
  picture: string;
  sub: string;
  updated_at: string;
  process.env.AUTH0_NAMESPACE + "/roles":string
}
```

Since I set up the namespace on auth0 server, it is attached to use user object as string. Since i want to hide it from the users, I thought this way would work but i am getting this error:

```
 Property or signature expected.// this warning comes for process.

 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.// this is for type "string".
```

I converted this line to this :

```
   `${process.env.AUTH0_NAMESPACE!}/roles`:string
```

I am getting same errors. Is there a way to use env variables as key value of the interface or i just have to explicitly write what the key is.
I use this interface here:

```
export const isAuthorized = (user: IUser, role: string) => {
  return (
    user &&
    user[process.env.AUTH0_NAMESPACE! + "/roles"] &&
    user[process.env.AUTH0_NAMESPACE! + "/roles"].includes(role)
  );
};
```

When I explicitly add the namespace to interface, I get this error in `isAuthorized`:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'IUser'.
```

No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'IUser'